# Mac issue with file encoding

Tags: macos, utf-8, character-encoding, file-encodings

I have a script which is reading some data from one server and storing it in a file. But the file seems somehow corrupt.  I can print it to the display, but checking the file with `file` produces

```
bash$ file -I filename  
filename: text/plain; charset=unknown-8bit
```

Why is it telling me that the encoding is unknown?  The first line of the file displays for me as

```
“The Galaxy A5 and A3 offer a beautifully crafted full metal unibody
```

A hex dump reveals that the first three bytes are 0xE2, 0x80, 0x9C followed by the regular ASCII text `The Galaxy A5`...

What's wrong?  Why does `file` tell me the encoding is unknown, and what is it actually?

Comment: Without access to the file *or* some sort of indication what's in it and how it's broken; no, we cannot.  Maybe check out the [`character-encoding` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info) for some tips for how to ask a moderately intelligent question.

Comment: No, "Mac" does not silently change any encodings. Maybe something in your particular workflow is, but since we have no idea what that is, we cannot help you with it.

Comment: simply printing on the terminal is working perfectly fine. Just redirecting it to the file is creating issues.

Comment: So your only claim to "failure" is the output if `file`? Maybe `file` simply *cannot guess the encoding*, but other than that everything's fine...!?

Comment: yeah, but even when I am telling the editor or vi to open as utf-8, it is unable to do so

Comment: Then maybe it's not UTF-8. Why do you think it should be?

Comment: Then what can be the issue? How it is working when simply printing on the terminal

Comment: I checked it on Linux, its working fine there.

Comment: You continue to fail to supply the information we have requested.  A file which is not UTF-8 will print fine in the terminal if your terminal is set up to use the same encoding as the file.  But we cannot guess what it is; all you are telling is is that it is definitely not UTF-8.

Comment: What more information should I supply? Can you try to elaborate?

Comment: The very first comment up there has some concrete advice.  Briefly, a hex dump of a few bytes should already do wonders, especially if those bytes are something else than plain 7-bit ASCII, and especially especially if you can tell us what they should display as.

Comment: I am getting this "â<80><9c>The Galaxy A5 and A3 offer a beautifully crafted full metal unibody" inspite of "“The Galaxy A5 and A3 offer      a beautifully crafted full metal unibody"

Comment: I updated your question with hopefully relevant and correct information from comments.  Please review, especially where I had to guess.

Comment: Thats fine, thanks for editing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information in the question, the file is a perfectly good UTF-8 file.  The first three bytes encode [LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK (U+201C)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm) aka a curly quote.

Maybe your version of `file` is really old.

Comment: If you are still having trouble, maybe post a new question with adequate diagnostics.  You can bisect the file to find the problematic bytes (delete half, see if the problem persists; if not, restore the problematic half, and proceed iteratively with deleting half of *that*, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use iconv to convert the file into the desired charset.  E.G.

```
iconv --from-code=UTF8 --to-code=YOURTARGET
```

To get a list of supported targets, use the --list flag.

Comment: I tried it, it is showing iconv: conversion from unknown-8bit unsupported

Comment: Do you know the charset from the remote server?  You should be able to specify it to do the conversion.

Comment: Even if it is unknown, you should be able to specify the --from=UTF8 flag to override the assumptions and force proper conversion.